# How to check data is coming in php (using GET method)

Tags: php, post, methods, get

I'm working with a small project using Module SIM 808 and web server.

I used GET method to transfer data to my web, the data is sent via URL.

```
Example: www.mywebsiteaddress/?data1=sensor1_value&data2=sensor2_value.
```

My website is written in PHP. I read data by using <`?php echo $_GET['data1']; ?>` .
Now I want to ask, how to check the data is coming. I wish that every time there is new data to it will automatically be "echo".

Is there something like a "Interrupt Service Rountie in Microcontroller" ?.

That is all of my code:

```
<?php
 @$data1_value=$_REQUEST['data1'];
 @$data2_value=$_REQUEST['data2'];
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Receive Data Using GET Method</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 40px">
        <form action="index.php" method="GET">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" >Data Receive From Module SIM 808</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data1</td>
                    <td><input style="font-size: 40px" type="text" name="data1" value="<?php echo @$data1_value ?>" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data2</td>
                    <td><input style=" font-size: 40px" type="text" name="data2" value="<?php echo @$data2_value ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

After I send data from my module sim, my data not appear in the textbox. 
Where is my data and why ????????

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here is my code

Answer (score 0):

you can get variable passed throught url with $_GET variable.

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

if you want to be sure to catch every htttp get variable passing throught your PHP application, you need to that every link point to a single index.php file.

so you can read content of $_GET, and redirect user to a page.